# Merging two tsv files by matching items of a column in python

Tags: python, merge

I have two tab separated (tsv) files. I want to get an output in tsv file that matches the items of specific columns of two files. I am new in python, it would be great if I get some comments.

input file1:

```
#comment one
#comment two and more
ab123    1    339    GT    +  s4
ab222    3    23    CT    -  se4
ab1100    3    523    AA    +  aa11
ab2211    20    166    TT    +  ss
```

input file2:

```
ab123    1
ab1100    3
```

Expected output is the first 4 columns of input file1 by matching to 1st column of file2:

```
ab123    1    339    GT 
ab1100    3    523    AA
```

The code I am trying with is:

```
with open("file1") as data:
        for line1 in data:
                with open("file2") as id:
                    for line2 in id:
                        if str(line2) in line1:
                            print line1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way is to generate a dict by using `file1` and iterate the list which is generated by reading `file2`, and extend this list, then use `join()` method to print it:

```
with open('1.csv') as f1, open('2.csv') as f2:
    d1 = {tuple(i.split()[:2]): i.split()[2:] for i in f1.read().split('\n')}

    for i in f2.read().split('\n'):
        tmp = i.split()
        if tuple(tmp[:2]) in d1:
            print(" ".join(tmp+(d1[tuple(tmp[:2])][:2])))
```

Output:

```
ab123 1 339 GT
ab1100 3 523 AA
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worker perfectly @McGrady

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the `csv` module to read the `tab-separated` value file (`tsv` file), just mention that the `delimiter='\t'`, below is the code:

```
import csv
with open('file1.tsv','rb') as tsv1 , open('file2.tsv', 'rb') as tsv2:
    tsv1 = csv.reader(tsv1, delimiter='\t')    
    tsv2 = csv.reader(tsv2, delimiter='\t')
    tsv1_list=list(tsv1)
    tsv2_list=list(tsv2)
    result = [e1[:4] for e1 in tsv1_list for e2 in tsv2_list if e1[0]==e2[0]]
    print result
```

Output:

```
[['ab123', '1', '339', 'GT'], ['ab1100', '3', '523', 'AA']]
```